# How to combine test statistics and p-values from the same (stochastic) test repeated on a single dataset?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, simulation, goodness-of-fit, combining-p-values

I would like to assess a generative model $M$'s goodness-of-fit using a simulation-based approach: I simulate some data from $M$, then compute a test statistic $T$ that measures how similar the simulated data is to the real data.

However, $T$ is fairly variable across runs: In addition to variability introduced in the simulation step, computing $T$ involves a stochastic optimization procedure whose results typically differ somewhat across runs. This procedure is computationally intensive and can only be done $5$-$10$ times in practice.

**Question:** Is it possible to combine results across a few runs to obtain a more stable estimate of $T$ and its associated $p$-value? I know that under $H_0$, $T$ is (approximately) asymptotically normal with known mean and variance, but am not sure whether this helps. I also am aware of [computing the harmonic mean of $p$-values for combining dependent tests](https://www.pnas.org/content/116/4/1195), but this would only combine the $p$-values, not the $T$'s as well.